# how can we join fields on kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

i had:
essaye YES **Idform 2** Nom Salim Prénom benabdeslam _id xW5cvogBINggXK4roNBx _index 11 _score -

essaye YES **Idform 2** Nomform Electronic Université USTO _id x25dvogBINggXK4rrd**your text**Cv _index 22 _score
i'm working on elk project, iwould like to join the two lines that we see on the photo to get somthing like ""essaye YES Idform 2 Nom Salim Prénom benabdesla Nomform Electronic Université USTO"" since i have the same Idform

[exepmle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtJ50.png)

Comment: Hello, what you are trying to say? What is the issue and the question here, please provide more details accurately for further discussion~

Answer (score 0):

- If the data is in the multiple indices you should use the [enrich policy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/match-enrich-policy-type.html).
- If the data is in the same index you can use the [transform](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-examples.html).

Note: Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do that like in a regular database.